# Python attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'asctime'

Tags: python, clock, alarm

I am trying to make an alarm clock in Python, but my code seems to not be working.  Can you please check it?

```
import time
from time import localtime
from time import asctime
from time import sleep
import datetime


def Checktime():
        global time
        time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        return time

while True:   
    Checktime()
    print(time[11:-5])
    sleep(2)
    print("Done")
```

The error I am getting in Idle3 is:

```
 16:40:18
    Done
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\time test.py", line 14, in <module>
    Checktime()
    File "C:\Python34\time test.py", line 10, in Checktime
    time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'asctime'
```

Comment: `time = time.asctime(...)` what did you *expect* this to do?! How do you access `time` (the module) after you assign this?

Answer (score 2):

The first time you execute

```
time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

then the global name `time` is bound to the module. And so you call the `asctime()` method which returns a string, which you bind to the global name `time`.

The next time you execute

```
time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

then the global name `time` is a string.

You should reconsider your attempt to use `time` to mean two different things. I suggest that you stop using `global` at all. As a general rule you should attempt to avoid doing that. The function already returns a value. That is good enough.

The code can be written like this:

```
import time
import datetime

def Checktime():
    return time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

while True:   
    asctime = Checktime()
    print(asctime[11:-5])
    sleep(2)
    print("Done")
```

FWIW, `CheckTime()` is a weak name for a function. A name that begins with `get` would seem more informative.